# Delete MySQL row using where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to delete duplicate rows according to some fileds.
When I'm running the query below:

```
delete
    from slowmo_vid as sv1, slowmo_vid as sv2
    where sv1.video_id = '2luh6g3ni5ex'
    and sv1.slowmo_end_t<=sv2.slowmo_end_t;
```

I'm getting the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as sv1, slowmo_vid as sv2
where sv1.video_id = '2luh6g3ni5ex'
and sv1.slowmo_end' at line 2
```

The fields of the tables are : id, video_id internal_uri, slowmo_end_t

Comment: if you wan't use multi Tables for the DELETE use the `JOIN` statement instead of `FROM Table1, Table2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be trying to do an ANSI-92 style inner join inside a `DELETE` statement.  But the `WHERE` clause cannot simultaneously be used to enforce the join *and* enforce a restriction on a result set.  Instead, do the following explicit `INNER JOIN` to remove the records you want.  Notice that it is clear what role the `WHERE` clause is playing.

Update: If you want to delete all records *except* for the one containing the max `video_id` then you can add a nested subquery to the `WHERE` clause.

```
DELETE sv1.*
FROM slowmo_vid sv1
INNER JOIN slowmo_vid sv2 ON sv1.slowmo_end_t <= sv2.slowmo_end_t
WHERE sv1.video_id = '2luh6g3ni5ex' AND
    sv1.video_id <> (SELECT x.id
                     FROM (SELECT MAX(t.video_id) AS id 
                             FROM slowmo_vid t) x)
```

Comment: When I'm running the query its delete all the records that satisfy this condition. Is there a way to delete all of the records except one? I tried to add limit 1 at the end of the query but it didn't help

Comment: Which record do you wish to keep and what is the logic behind this decision?

Comment: I want to keep the record with max id because it have more updated data

Comment: I updated the query.  Give it a whirl and let us know if you have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

> You can specify multiple tables in a DELETE statement to delete rows
>   from one or more tables depending on the particular condition in the
>   WHERE clause. However, you cannot use ORDER BY or LIMIT in a
>   multiple-table DELETE. The table_references clause lists the tables
>   involved in the join. Its syntax is described in Section 12.2.8.1,
>   “JOIN Syntax”.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html

The example in the manual is:

```
DELETE t1, t2 FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 INNER JOIN t3
WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND t2.id=t3.id;
```

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use aliases on DELETE statement. You can try with:

```
DELETE FROM myAlias USING `my_table` AS myAlias
```

Or try without any aliases